# Dual-boot Ubuntu cannot access the Windows drive that it was installed on with wubi

Tags: linux, partition, windows, dual-boot, wubi

I had Windows with two drives C: and D:. In the drive C:, I have my Windows. In the drive D:, I had my all other files and data. I installed Ubuntu in the drive D:, without deleting any data from it.
So when I boot my laptop, in  boot menu I see both "Windows 7" and "Ubuntu".

When I boot up with Ubuntu, it works well, but I don't have access my data in drive D: (where I installed Ubuntu) anymore, but when I boot up with Windows, I have access to it.

How can I have access my data in drive D: from Ubuntu?

This is some information:

```
sky@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for sky: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2f56f4c5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *    21585920    21790719      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        21790720   144670719    61440000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       144670782   625141759   240235489    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       144670784   562580234   208954725+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       562581504   617027583    27223040   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       617029632   625141759     4056064   82  Linux swap / Solaris


sky@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      10698000   3015236   7116288  30% /
udev             1947220         4   1947216   1% /dev
tmpfs             782716       880    781836   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1956788       156   1956632   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5      208954724 114865916  94088808  55% /host
sky@ubuntu:~$

sky@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none            swap    loop,sw         0       0
sky@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: please can you add the text from command `df` and `cat /etc/fstab` ? don't hesitate to [edit] your question to add any information. because the problem you're describing is really strange as you cannont install ubuntu on a ntfs drive

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu autonomously, or as a file in the Windows partition (Wubi)? Please open a terminal and copy-paste the output of the following commands: `sudo fdisk -l` and `df`.

Comment: I'm sure op installed Ubuntu via Wubi.

Comment: wubi is not possible for a while now no ?

Comment: I installed it via Wubi

Comment: It sounds like you are mounting your drive over the Windows data. Please add the output of `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: I've been doing some research into this issue and it seems if in windows even 1 file on the data drive shared by both windows and linux is accessed by windows, then windows will lock access to the whole drive depending on windows shutdown mode. I'm still trying to get to work out how to shut windows down nicely, and the restart (with update sometimes) seems to work for me. If I choose the shutdown option, I'm locked out. Something to do with windows fastboot...I know... that's a contradiction in terms eh!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that :

> From the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)
>
> How do I access the Windows drives?
>
> The Windows partition where you installed Wubi is available as /host within Ubuntu (Places > Computer > File System > Host) All the other partitions will be available under Places > > Removable Media

From askUbuntu: [Wubi: How do I find partition windows on ubuntu ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/158458/93232)

And as fstab show a mount point `/host`, you can try form a terminal :

```
cd /host
ls -l
```

or from Nautilus type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and then type the path /host to access your files.